# RailsテストのArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)を解決したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, テスト

## 環境

Rails 6.0.4
Ruby 3.0.2
Docker

RailsチュートリアルにDockerで環境構築をして開発を行っています
現在10章まで進んでいるのですが、minitestでテストを行っており、機能実装前の受け入れテストコードを毎度書いていくのですが、テストコードを書くたびに必ず、「呼び出し側の引数の数」と「メソッド側の仮引数」ズレでエラーが起きてしまいます

## エラー文

▼ターミナル

```
$ docker-compose exec web bundle exec rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 2821
Started with run options --seed 33308

ERROR["test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000aaab11031490 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.3196210830064956]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.32s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

test/21: [=============================================================================            ] 87% Time: 00:00:01,  ETA: 00:00:00
  24/24: [========================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.93922s
24 tests, 46 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

## エラーが出ているところのテストを記述している部分

▼test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email } } # 22行目
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  # test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
  #   log_in_as(@other_user)
  #   get edit_user_path(@user)
  #   assert_flash.empty?
  #   assert_redirected_to root_url
  # end

  # test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
  #   log_in_as(@other_user)
  #   patct user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email } }
  #   assert_flash.ematy?
  #   assert_redirected_to root_url
  # end
end
```

▼test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

  # テストユーザーがログイン中の場合にtrueを返す
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # テストユーザーとしてログインする
  def log_in_as(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  # テストユーザーとしてログインする
  def log_in_as(user, password: 'password', remember_me: '1')
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: user.email, password: password, remember_me: remember_me } }
  end
end
```

## これまでやったこと

どうしてこのエラーが発生するのかは、色々ググってみて下記の記事を参考に知ることができましたが、実際自分のコードのどのようにあてはめたら良いのかわかりません。お力を貸してください！

[ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given A, expected B)のA,Bの引数の判断方法](https://qiita.com/yo0917/items/20c165a3b06805bf2e37)

[サンプルコードでわかる！Ruby 3.0の主な新機能と変更点 Part 2 - 新機能と変更点の総まとめ](https://zenn.dev/jnchito/articles/24e0bd7fd1045d#hash%23each%E3%81%8C%E5%BF%85%E3%81%9A2%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%81%AE%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%99%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F)

Answer (score 0):

以下のように記述してparamsの前のカンマを削除してみるとどうでしょうか？

```rb
patch user_path(@user) params: { user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email } }
```

参考記事
[Railsチュートリアル 第７章 リスト7.23のテストでArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)](https://qiita.com/syo19961113/items/c0c7f89a51954199fca0)